# How can I access winForm Common control inside helper class?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have windows form and want to use my below code inside my helper class. I made richtextbox and tabControl modifier public, but still I cant access the my richtextbox. It gives error at richTextBox1 saying

`The name richTextBox1 doesnt exist in the current context`

What I am doing wrong?

***helper class***

```
List<string> commentLines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code sample is pretty incomplete. However...

You'll need to pass a reference to the RichTextBox to the method or class constructor (depending on your code):

```
// HelperClass method
public static void UpdateCommentLines(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    List<string> commentLines = richTextBox.Lines.ToList();
}

// WinForm Code
public void DoSomething()
{
    HelperClass.UpdateCommentLines(this.richTextBox1);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at UpdateCommentLines(RichTextBox richTextBox): The type or namespace name 'RichTextBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user2744243 In the same file(the one in which you are getting this error),write this statement at the top of file; `using System.Windows.Forms;`.